# How can I queue up multiple flask app.routes to-do list?

Tags: python, flask, redis

I have some code that a few clients call via a webhook.  The problem is while one section of code gets ran, another webhook comes in and interrupts.  I'm afraid to use threading here because of the rate limits that one of the apis has.  Instead I would like for when a POST for /endpoint1, /endpoint2, /endpoint3 comes in, put it in a task to-do list, first in first out.

What would you suggest?

```
import os
import subprocess
from flask import Flask, request, abort

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/endpoint1', methods=['POST'])
def endpoint1method():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       import time
       print("Call some API")
       subprocess.call(['python', 'api1.py'], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
       time.sleep(1)
       print("Call some other API with rate limits")
       subprocess.call(['python', 'api1_with_limit.py'], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
       time.sleep(1)
       print("Send an email")
       subprocess.call(['python', 'api1_send_email'], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
       time.sleep(1)
       return 'success', 200
    else:
       abort(400)

@app.route('/endpoint2', methods=['POST'])
def endpoint2method():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       import time
       print("Call some API")
       subprocess.call(['python', 'api2.py'], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
       time.sleep(1)
       print("Call some other API with rate limits")
       subprocess.call(['python', 'api2_with_limit.py'], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
       time.sleep(1)
       print("Send an email")
       subprocess.call(['python', 'api2_send_email'], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
       time.sleep(1)
       return 'success', 200
    else:
       abort(400)

@app.route('/endpoint3', methods=['POST'])
def endpoint3method():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       import time
       print("Call some API")
       subprocess.call(['python', 'api3.py'], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
       time.sleep(1)
       print("Call some other API with rate limits")
       subprocess.call(['python', 'api3_with_limit.py'], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
       time.sleep(1)
       print("Send an email")
       subprocess.call(['python', 'api3_send_email'], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
       time.sleep(1)
       return 'success', 200
    else:
       abort(400)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=80)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are probably looking for a queue or background jobs. This will listen for a certain task and will complete them one after another:

you can use

here is an example:

> Let’s write a task that adds two numbers together and returns the
> result. We configure Celery’s broker and backend to use Redis, create
> a celery application using the factor from above, and then use it to
> define the task.
>
> ```
> from flask import Flask
>
> flask_app = Flask(__name__)
> flask_app.config.update(
>     CELERY_BROKER_URL='redis://localhost:6379',
>     CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://localhost:6379'
> )
> celery = make_celery(flask_app)
>
> @celery.task()
> def add_together(a, b):
>     return a + b
>
> This task can now be called in the background:
>
> result = add_together.delay(23, 42)
> result.wait()  # 65
> ```

source: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/celery/

you can find another great tutorial here: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xxii-background-jobs